# Let $G$ be a finite group with a normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ has order 7. $G$ is isomorphic to $ H × G/H$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with a normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ has order 7 . Then $G$ is isomorphic to $ H × G/H$ .
Is this True/False.
I don't kbow how to start , so please help!

Comment: (This is asked in Tifr 2018)

Comment: What if $G$ is cyclic?

Comment: We can say $G$ is abelian.

Comment: What happens if it is cyclic or abelian , i didn't get it @Lord Shark the Unkown

Comment: Is your instinct for a proof or a counterexample? Obviously $G$ has order divisible by $7$. What happens with the simplest examples you know of such groups.

Comment: Is $\times$ denote external direct product

Comment: Or you could take the non-abelian of order $203=7.29$

Comment: @the_fox could you please elaborate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Take the cyclic group $\;C_{49}\;$ and let $\;H\;$ be its subgroup of order $\;7\;$ ...

Comment: So G$\times $G/H is not cyclic while G is cylic? So not isomorphic... Could you please tell me how you think about this example, it isn't obvious for me .

Comment: Is $\times$ denote external direct product?

Comment: @CloudJR Remember that $\;C_n\times C_m\;$ is cyclic iff $\;(n,m)=1\;$ , and in this case $\;C_n\times C_m\cong C_{nm}\;$ . From here that a cyclic group of order a power of a prime cannot be a non-trivial direct product.

Comment: Thanks a lot...